# Heroku fails to detect Hugo app matching buildpack

Tags: heroku, hugo

I created a Hugo application which I wanted to deploy through Heroku.

Following Hugo's instructions on their [github readme](https://github.com/roperzh/heroku-buildpack-hugo), it says to create a Heroku app with the command:

```
$ heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/roperzh/heroku-buildpack-hugo.git
```

followed by:

```
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

Upon doing so, however, I keep getting an error:

```
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/go.tgz buildpack
```

and the push ultimately fails.

Most of what I've looked up tells me that it needs a specification of what language is being used, which in this case is Go.

But even when doing:

```
heroku buildpacks:set -a myproject heroku/go
```

It tells me:

```
 !    The buildpack heroku/go is already set on your app.
```

So, if it's already set on my app, then why can't it detect an app matching the buildpack?

Answer (score 0):

Check your hugo version using

```
hugo version
```

and then set your hugo version on heroku
for example 0.40

```
heroku config:set HUGO_VERSION=0.40 -a <your app name>
```